# How can I extablish a STOMP connection from JMeter?

Tags: websocket, jmeter, stomp

We are trying to run load testing in JMeter against a WebSocket application created in a Spring Boot (STOMP) application having CONNECT, SUBSCRIBE, and SEND endpoints, e.g.:

```
CONNECT
accept-version:1.2,1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

^@
```

```
SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-001
destination:/user/aa/queue/notify

^@
```

```
SEND
destination:/app/register
content-length:1232

{"transactionId":"arr2f6c7-a7d3-45a3-aeb5-baacf4d742cea2","sessionId":"aa","functionId":"fdsfd" }
^@
```

In JMeter we can see the WebSocket connection is establishing but the send endpoint not reaching the server. There is no error in JMeter.

Tried the same in postman also, but there is no response.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't support WebSockets out of the box, you will need a plugin for that.

For example [JMeter Websocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) support WebSockets.

Check out [Using Websocket samplers in JMeter with STOMP](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/issues/39/using-websocket-samplers-in-jmeter-with) discussion which suggests ending the message with NULL char like this:

```
String s = "CONNECT\n" +       
       "login:${wsToken}\n" +
                   "passcode:\n" +
                   "accept-version:1.1,1.0\n" +
                   "heart-beat:20000,0\n" +
                   "\n" + 
                   '\0'  // note: NULL char at end
                   ;

vars.put("wsStompData", s);
```

so I belive if you play this trick you will be able to send the message successfully.

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)

Comment: This solution didnt work.is there any way to put direct plugin in jmeter

Comment: Yes, please [develop the plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development) and [contribute it](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html) by creating a merge request